# A summary plot for mean, standard deviation, median, min and max

Tags: data-visualization

I have mean, standard devation, median, min, and max of a dataset, but not the source data.  Which summary plot would you recommend for visualising different groups in the dataset?

Comment: a boxplot is the way to go; doesn't incorporate stddev by default but could plot +-3 stddevs as one usually does the IQR (and I've seen plenty of boxplots throw a mean on there as well as a median).

Comment: @TTZ There are a few previously asked variants of this question; I'd be inclined to mark range and median in one colour (sort of like a boxplot without the box) and a mean and mean $\pm$ sd in a second colour, clearly identifying the elements in the key. You might want to combine elements from 
here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dboST.png (median and extremes) and here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG05s.png (mean and sd)
(plots from here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77836/plotting-summary-statistics-with-mean-sd-min-and-max/77916#77916)

... ctd

Comment: ctd ... also see this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqxk3.png

(removing the grey line and red whiskers, the remaining elements could be overlaid; plot comes from here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74099/how-to-best-visualize-one-sample-test/74105#74105)